# How to remove a GeoFire handle for the following observe in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, geofire

This is a question for Swift, Firebase and Geofire.

I would like to know how to remove a GeoFire handle for the following observer in Swift.

```
locationsEnd!.query(at: location, withRadius: 16.0).observe(GFEventType.init(rawValue: 0)!, with: {(key, location) in
```

The following works fine (in viewDidDisappear):

```
locationsEnd?.firebaseRef.removeAllObservers()
```

However with handle it does not:

```
var locationHandle: UInt = 0

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    //following does not work:
    locationsEnd?.firebaseRef.removeObserver(withHandle: locationHandle)
}

func aroundMe(_ location: CLLocation){

        locationHandle = locationsEnd!.query(at: location, withRadius: 16.0).observe(GFEventType.init(rawValue: 0)!, with: {(key, location) in

            //etc
        })
}
```

I've tried the locationHandle as follows, without success:

```
var locationHandle = FirebaseHandle()
var locationHandle: FirebaseHandle = 0
var locationHandle: UInt!
var locationHandle: UInt = 0
var locationHandle = FIRDatabaseHandle()
var locationHandle: FirebaseHandle = 0
```

Any suggestions would be great, as mentioned I can just remove all observers, but elsewhere I need to just remove a handle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

locationHandle is defined as an UInt in your code and it needs to be a FIRDatabaseHandle so

Here's an example of removing a Firebase handle

```
var myPostHandle : FIRDatabaseHandle?

func someFunc()
{
    myPostHandle = ref.child("posts").observeEventType(.childAdded,
      withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

            let postBody = snapshot.value!["body"] as! String

    })
}

func stopObserving()
{
    if myPostHandle != nil {
        ref.child("posts").removeObserverWithHandle(myPostHandle)
    }
}
```

For GeoFire it's more like this

```
let geofireRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
let center = CLLocation(latitude: 37.7832889, longitude: -122.4056973)
var circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: 0.6)

var queryHandle = circleQuery.observeEventType(.KeyEntered,
         withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
             //do something
})
```

then to remove, use the

```
circleQuery.removeObserverWithFirebaseHandle(queryHandle)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. tried that just now, doesn't seem to make a difference. I tried: 
var locationHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?
var locationHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle!
var locationHandle = FIRDatabaseHandle()
var locationHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle = 0

Comment: @PeterdeVries Added some quick example code to my answer, which is tested.

Comment: many thanks and indeed I have the same structure elsewhere, which works perfectly fine. The problem is with removing a GeoFire handle. removeAllObservers() works, removeObserver(withHandle: locationHandle) does not.

Comment: @PeterdeVries oops, I typed to fast. Please use removeObserverWithFirebaseHandle instead of removeObserverWithHandle.

Comment: I get: Value of type 'FIRDatabaseReference' has no member 'removeObserverWithFirebaseHandle'. Tried to change it to removeObserver(WithFirebasehandle: locationHandle), but swift asks me to put as before (removeObserver(withHandle)

Comment: @PeterdeVries You should be using GeoFire objects - GeoFire is built on Firebase but has it own objects..  Like a GFQuery for example which has the removeObserverWithFirebaseHandle function [GFQueryClassReference](https://geofire-ios.firebaseapp.com/docs/Classes/GFQuery.html#//api/name/removeObserverWithFirebaseHandle:)

Comment: That was what I had, but your answer put me in the right direction, as I had to declare the GFQuery, and remove the handle of the query, not of the firebaseRef. Many thanks. that worked!